# Likes on link wall post not counting on like button plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

The organization I work for has a blog with the like button working for each post.  Sometimes, we take blog post urls and post them as a link on our Facebook fan page.  The wall post gets hundreds of likes.  Why aren't these likes being reflected on the button's count on the blog?  Here is an example:

Blog post showing only 45 likes on the button: http://www.uwishunu.com/2012/01/photo-of-the-day-the-2012-nhl-winter-classic-puck-drops-at-3-p-m-today-at-citizens-bank-park-go-flyers/

Facebook Wall Post **referencing the blog post url** with 407 likes:  http://www.facebook.com/visitphilly/posts/201311466628610

According to like button's dev page:

> What makes up the number shown on my Like button?
>
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL

Am I reading this wrong or are we not doing something correctly?

Comment: I think it's because they are "liking" the wall post, not the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The likes you see on the post in feed are dedicated to post, not to content your application share!

Citing [documentation of Like Button Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> What makes up the number shown on my Like button?
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
> - The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

Comment: I guess the I am getting hung up on the third bullet point:
"The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL"
Wouldn't this count as a like on a story on facebook about the url??

Comment: I have feeling that `link` and `post` are behave a bit differently in that particular case, but can't provide any proof on this...

Comment: I found this forum where someone has the same question and people are telling him the same thing you guys are telling me... that likes on a wall post that features a url is not the same as liking the url and will therefore <i>not</i> increase the buttons count.  I just feel like the third bullet point in FB's own documentation states otherwise.  http://forum.bokhorst.biz/forums/topic/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-number-of-likes-on-fb-be-the-same-as-on-the-website/

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem! And I'm 100% sure, this used to work.

I have a wp blog, a FB page and FB profile. I use Facebook Like plugin on the blog. So I write a post on the blog, post the link to FB page and share it to my FB profile. Then I get 10 likes on the link on FB page, 8 likes on the link on FB profile and 5 likes on the blog post itself. This used to count to 25 likes (10+8+5+ 2shares). But now, all of a sudden, I only get 7 likes (5 likes from the blog + 2 shares). It doesn't count those likes on the FB Page and FB profile anymore.

I know this used to work, because I could see it in action. People would like the post on my FB Page and the count would go up on my wp blog post.

Now sure where the problem is. Is this something new in FB or is it an error?? I've read dozens of blogs on this issue and am dealing with this for a whole week now, but this is the first post (reply actually) that says those likes shouldn't be counted together. :/

Comment: We are still having the same issue/question.  It appears that sometime in December of 2011 the Like button stopped counting the Likes on link wall posts.  Again, not sure if this is a Facebook change or something that we are doing incorrectly.  This thread on the regular Stack Overflow asks the same question and is given a detailed answer as to why the wall post likes and blog post likes are separate but no explanation as to why/when this happened.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305039/facebook-like-count-on-website-is-much-lower-than-facebook-page