# Facebook 'Like' count on website is much lower than Facebook page

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

The "Like" count on my articles has been very low for the past few months. For example, an article has 190+ "Likes" on this Facebook page:
http://www.facebook.com/BatmanNewsCom/posts/282806528452384

and 321+ "Likes" on this Facebook page:
http://www.facebook.com/TDKRises/posts/208282902603624

But my website is only displaying 157 "Likes" for that article. This has been a problem with every article I've posted since around the middle of December. Any idea what could be wrong? Shouldn't they be in sync with the Facebook pages, and any other "Likes" elsewhere?

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 321+ "Likes" on https://www.facebook.com/TDKRises/posts/208282902603624 are "Likes" on that actual POST on facebook. The 157 "Likes" on this article http://batman-news.com/2012/02/09/heath-ledgers-joker-the-dark-knight-featured-in-oscars-ad/ are "Likes" for that URL. Facebook does not add "Likes" for a URL and "Likes" for a POST containing the said URL together; they are kept as two separate entities.

For instance, here's a link using FQL to query the `link_stat` table.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22http://batman-news.com/2012/02/09/heath-ledgers-joker-the-dark-knight-featured-in-oscars-ad/%22&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAP3WZAm1IZCLto32KgEjjYbk5zCsRyZAf7YSSQyxBdqBXZAZBhqsKxZCpAnLUuOXV8lHzjmfuZCeJPRXv2GvBSmnENLVVlvhwZDZD`
```

And it returns this result:

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
   <link_stat>
       <url>
            http://batman-news.com/2012/02/09/heath-ledgers-joker-the-dark-knight-featured-in-oscars-ad/
        </url>
        <normalized_url>
            http://www.batman-news.com/2012/02/09/heath-ledgers-joker-the-dark-knight-featured-in-oscars-ad/
        </normalized_url>
        <share_count>104</share_count>
        <like_count>53</like_count>
        <comment_count>0</comment_count>
        <total_count>157</total_count>
        <commentsbox_count>0</commentsbox_count>
        <comments_fbid>10150538028142844</comments_fbid>
        <click_count>0</click_count>
    </link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

Which shows the "Like" count you're getting on your page to be how many people "share" that URL + how many people like that URL.

Now if you do a Graph API query against the post ID, you can see that the like count does differ between URL and post.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/117326344965823_208282902603624
```

With a response of:

```
{
   "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624",
   "from": {
      "name": "The Dark Knight Rises",
      "category": "Movie",
      "id": "117326344965823"
   },
   "story": "The Dark Knight Rises shared a link.",
   "story_tags": {
      "0": [
         {
            "id": 117326344965823,
            "name": "The Dark Knight Rises",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 21
         }
      ]
   },
   "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDJ1A-Ok89RPwkn&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fcdn.batman-news.com\u00252Fwp-content\u00252Fuploads\u00252F2012\u00252F02\u00252F846x476-175x165.jpg",
   "link": "http://batman-news.com/2012/02/09/heath-ledgers-joker-the-dark-knight-featured-in-oscars-ad/",
   "name": "Heath Ledger\u2019s \u2018The Dark Knight\u2019 Joker featured in Oscars ad",
   "caption": "batman-news.com",
   "description": "The Oscars air live on February 26th and today a new ad campaign was revealed. The ads all feature a reference to a great movie of the past. One of those great movies happens to be The Dark Knight...",
   "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
   "type": "link",
   "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:17:40+0000",
   "updated_time": "2012-02-10T17:38:52+0000",
   "shares": {
      "count": 29
   },
   "likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "Ahmed Yagoub",
            "id": "1484476725"
         },
         {
            "name": "Ryan Watkins",
            "id": "725002161"
         },
         {
            "name": "Buddy George Fonseca",
            "id": "100001448442792"
         },
         {
            "name": "S\u00edlvio Teixeira Leite",
            "id": "100002240617284"
         }
      ],
      "count": 324
   },
   "comments": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786248",
            "from": {
               "name": "Chalerm Chaimongkol",
               "id": "100002659449106"
            },
            "message": "You are the best, Heath Ledger. :)",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:20:59+0000",
            "likes": 1
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786250",
            "from": {
               "name": "Bradley Wayne Instance",
               "id": "100003120853077"
            },
            "message": "Long Live Joker :)",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:21:08+0000",
            "likes": 5
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786259",
            "from": {
               "name": "Nilabh Singh",
               "id": "531292994"
            },
            "message": "Greatest character ever in the history of Cinema.\nR.I.P Heath Andrew Ledger.\nYou were a legend.",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:22:15+0000",
            "likes": 10
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786291",
            "from": {
               "name": "Camie Chaos",
               "id": "517844186"
            },
            "message": "\u003C3\u003C3\u003C3",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:25:45+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786313",
            "from": {
               "name": "Anand Tiwari",
               "id": "1321947394"
            },
            "message": "you are a legend!!!",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:28:51+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786314",
            "from": {
               "name": "Manoj Biswal",
               "id": "100001010999210"
            },
            "message": "indeed great character",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:29:13+0000",
            "likes": 1
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786327",
            "from": {
               "name": "Lee Duller",
               "id": "100003188571395"
            },
            "message": "Love that joker!",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:36:30+0000",
            "likes": 2
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786329",
            "from": {
               "name": "Ben Cribbett",
               "id": "633801171"
            },
            "message": "was a amazing joker, i have him tattoo'd on my arm R.I.P. :(",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:37:19+0000",
            "likes": 2
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786346",
            "from": {
               "name": "Eric Jones",
               "id": "1343067459"
            },
            "message": "GLAD he won, but screw the Oscars.  TDK should've been up for many more awards, Ledger should have won BEST ACTOR (not supporting as anyone who has actually seen the movie knows it is as centered around him as much as Wayne/Batman), and Harry Potter & Xmen: First Class are snubbed this year?!?\n\nin a year of HIGHLY overrated & underwhelming films?  what a joke & w/out a great punchline like The Joker would deliver.\n\nwill find anything better to do than waste time on this stupid awards show this year.  hell, i missed most of the SAG Awards and they're way better than the Oscars.\n\nbut First Class was one of the best of the year, bar none, and topped a good summer of VERY good blockbusters (minus Green Lantern, of course).  to be totally snubbed & disrespected just shows what a bunch of geriatric douchebag assclowns The Academy is full of.",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:45:32+0000",
            "likes": 2
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786381",
            "from": {
               "name": "Boris Kopp",
               "id": "100003049418181"
            },
            "message": "\"You changed everything.\" Thats true, Heath. You really changed everything with this once on a lifetime performance in The Dark Knight. In this role and many others, you stay alive in our hearts.",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:54:59+0000",
            "likes": 2
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786383",
            "from": {
               "name": "Ninad Naik",
               "id": "100003125720497"
            },
            "message": "Why so serious...???\r\nLets put some smile on your face....:)\r\nHail Joker....!!!!\r\n",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T17:56:08+0000",
            "likes": 2
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786395",
            "from": {
               "name": "Taylan Erdem",
               "id": "100001437162326"
            },
            "message": "the dark knight is old it is the dark knight rises!!!",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T18:00:09+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786510",
            "from": {
               "name": "Nerd Rawk",
               "category": "Entertainer",
               "id": "259582000764594"
            },
            "message": "We discuss comic books in our latest podcast! http://nerd-rawk.podomatic.com/entry/2012-02-07T21_09_20-08_00",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T18:25:58+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786512",
            "from": {
               "name": "Nisargh Ny S",
               "id": "100000537517253"
            },
            "message": "hope jhonny depp replaces joker..",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T18:26:29+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786532",
            "from": {
               "name": "Sergio Rossell Reyes",
               "id": "1038781683"
            },
            "message": "wow, seems like the oscar's producers really want to make people watch this year's show.",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T18:33:36+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786560",
            "from": {
               "name": "Andrew Kilian",
               "id": "625429396"
            },
            "message": "Borderline bad taste.",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T18:40:29+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786780",
            "from": {
               "name": "Peter Ike Amadi",
               "id": "1617233525"
            },
            "message": "Heath, you changed things at the Oscars. Forever. You see some men aren't looking for anything logical, they can't be bought, bullied, reasoned or negotiated with. Some men just want to watch the Oscars burn...",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T19:49:05+0000",
            "likes": 5
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_786844",
            "from": {
               "name": "Luke Hobbs",
               "id": "1123606586"
            },
            "message": "and in 2013 tom hardy will win an oscar for his amazing performance in the dark knight rises as bane",
            "created_time": "2012-02-09T20:11:48+0000",
            "likes": 4
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_787859",
            "from": {
               "name": "Jackson Krista",
               "id": "100000650880066"
            },
            "message": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyNqmiX_Xl8",
            "created_time": "2012-02-10T02:32:41+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "117326344965823_208282902603624_790194",
            "from": {
               "name": "Kishan Herchandani",
               "id": "1849953622"
            },
            "message": "he deserves that",
            "created_time": "2012-02-10T17:38:52+0000",
            "likes": 2
         }
      ],
      "count": 20
   }
}
```

Showing the likes to be 324 for the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Derek. Did they change this behavior within the last couple months? It used to be a combination of the "Likes" on the Facebook post and the URL.

It bothers me that my articles have so few "Likes" now. I used to consistently have 400+ "Likes" next to my articles because it was counting them from all of Facebook, not just my website.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I just started working with Facebook within the last couple months. I'm going to edit my answer to show some FQL / Graph API queries to show you what's up though.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher, I agree that up until fairly recently the Likes that a url got when shared as a link on a wall post used to increase the count shown on the Like button.  I started a thread about this on the Facebook specific Stack Overflow here:  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8944567/likes-on-link-wall-post-not-counting-on-like-button-plugin

Please let me know if you figure out anything else.

Comment: Glad to hear it's not just me Erik. I noticed it around mid-December and I'm running a WordPress website too. Could it be a WordPress thing?

Comment: It looks like Facebook is aware of this issue. They replied to a report in mid-January:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/190103447754156?browse=search_4f4d9bd96c2a78393932208

Hopefully we get a fix soon...